# Ways to ensure unique instances of a class?

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm looking for different ways to ensure that each instance of a given class is a uniquely identifiable instance.

For example, I have a `Name` class with the field `name`. Once I have a `Name` object with `name` initialised to John Smith I don't want to be able to instantiate a different `Name` object also with the name as John Smith, or if instantiation does take place I want a reference to the orginal object to be passed back rather than a new object.

I'm aware that one way of doing this is to have a static factory that holds a `Map` of all the current Name objects and the factory checks that an object with John Smith as the name doesn't already exist before passing back a reference to a `Name` object.

Another way I could think of off the top of my head is having a static Map in the `Name` class and when the constructor is called throwing an exception if the value passed in for `name` is already in use in another object, however I'm aware [throwing exceptions in a constructor is generally a bad idea](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ11-J.+Be+wary+of+letting+constructors+throw+exceptions).

Are there other ways of achieving this?

Comment: You want a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: you should better go with the first one: - static factory

Comment: @MarcB op doesn't want singleton. he might have many instances of the same class, but these instances must be identifiable.

Comment: same basic principal holds, just instead of checking only for a single instance, you have a property that keeps track of the names and only instantiate if the name wasn't already done before.

Comment: @MarcB I'm aware of the singleton pattern but I thought that ensures only one instance of a class is possible? I want multiple instances, different values. Sorry if the question isn't making that clear. edit: Only saw first comment before posting.

Comment: **Unit Of Work pattern** is something i've used for this

Comment: @MarcB: Except that the patterns for programming a Singleton don't really work for what the OP asked for.

Comment: I'm reminded of [this C++ FQA quote](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/inheritance-mother.html#fqa-23.2): "This tells us something about the intellectual diet of people calling trivial combinations of basic language constructs 'strategies' and 'patterns'." You need a function. This function will check some collection of previously created Xs and return one of those or create and return a new one or an exception. Seeing as you already know this much, I fail to see how asking for an enumeration of the various names for the same is productive.

Comment: `I'm aware that one way of doing this is to have a static factory that holds a Map...` So why don't you want to do it this way?

Comment: Your question would be a better one if you could tell us why you don't find the static factory method satisfactory, and are therefore searching for alternatives.   Personally, the static factory approach gets my vote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The actual class I'll be using it on is almost as simple as the `Name` class I use in the example, it just seems a waste to have a NameFactory and a Name class to get uniqueness for something so small, I was wondering if there was a more succinct way.

Comment: But you don't need all that; all you need is a `static` `ActualClass` `Create(string name)` method in your actual class that checks a static list of previous instances, and returns a new `MyClass` object if `name` is unique, or throws/returns `null` if the name already exists.

Comment: Sorry, massive facepalm, I don't actually need a NameFactory (or my equivalent) since there would one be one sub-class, the static method alone in `Name` would work fine. I was also just curious if there were other ways of ensuring uniqueness apart from the method(s) I mentioned. edit: Sorry hadn't seen your post!

Answer (score 13):

Actually you have already answered your question. Your first way should be more effective here. Using `static factory` is always preferable than `constructor` wherever you think you can. So, you can avoid using `Constructor` in this case, else you would have `throw some exception` if an instance already exists with the given name.

So, you can create a static factory method: - `getInstanceWithName(name)` which will get the already available instance with that name, and if it does not exist, it will create a new instance, and make your `constructor` private, as it should mostly be done when dealing with `static factories`.

Also, for that you need to maintain a static `List` or `Map` of all the unique instances created, in your `Factory` class.

**EDIT**: -

You should certainly go through - [Effective Java - Item#1 : Consider Static factories over Constructors](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec1). You can't get better explanation than that book.

Comment: That's something which the OP already has thought of.

Comment: +1 for the link, which seems to clearly address some of the OP's concerns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Yeah that book is the best source for most of the topics like these. And that's the very first item in fact. :)

Comment: +1 for Effective Java, I do have the book, sitting in my bag now actually :) However I was just curious as to other ways of achieving the uniqueness *apart* from the static factory/static method and the exception in the constructor. If there aren't any then I'll accept this.

Comment: @Peanut. Sure. That is the best resource to dig in to get more information.

Comment: As an interesting example, one could examine the usage of IntegerCache when calling Integer.getValue(...). (For more http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 6):

Mentions of **Effective Java** seems to add a lot of credibility so this answer draws on:

- Effective Java Item 8: Obey the general contract when overriding equals
- Effective Java Item 9: Always override the hashCode when you override equals
- Effective Java Item 15: Minimise mutability

I would take a step back and question why you care if there are more than one instance of this name object.

I rarely need to do this kind of object pooling. It is my guess that the OP is doing this so they can simply compare their `Name` objects with `==`. Or use the `Name` objects inside a `HashMap` or similar as the key.

If so this is something that can be solved through [proper implementation of `equals()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17).

Like so:

```
public final class Name {
  private final String name;

  public Name(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
      name = ""; //or exception if you like
    }
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Name)) {
      return false;
    }
    Name other = (Name) o;
    return other.name.equals(name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Once done the following is true:

```
Name a = new Name("weston");
Name b = new Name("weston");
assert(a.equals(b)); //same but:
assert(a!=b); //not the same instance
//test out the Name instances in a hashmap:
HashMap<Name,Object> map = new HashMap<Name,Object>();
Object detailsIn = new Object();
map.put(a,detailsIn);
Object detailsOut = map.get(b);
assert(detailsIn==detailsOut); //the map returned the same details object
//even though we put with `a` and got with `b` thanks to our correct equals implementation
```

I'm guessing your goal, but this way you can use the `Name` class in hash maps etc, and they do **not** have to be the exact same instance.

Comment: Example, please.

Comment: @RobertHarvey example of proper implementation?

Comment: Looks like you provided one.  But I'm not clear how this is any different from merely checking the Name property for equality in a static factory method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've tried to explain more, I am offering a complete alternative that does not require static factory at all and I am challenging the OPs starting point that they do not want to have more than once instance per name.

Comment: A valid reason to require unique objects is if you want a synchronized block to use the object as a monitor. Two objects which .equals() each other would not work.

Comment: @LeighCaldwell I would encourage objects used for synchronization to be private, as one of many measures to prevent deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

- Make `Name` an interface
- Create an interface `NameFactory` with a method `Name getByName(String)`
- Create an implementation of `NameFactory` with a `Map<String,WeakReference<Name>>` inside it
- `synchronize` on the map by name inside the `getByName` method before making new instances of `Name`
- Optionally, use a static private implementation of the `Name` interface inside your implementation of the `NameFactory`

This approach would let you ensure that:

- Only a single instance of `Name` exists at any time,
- There is no "Lingerer" memory leak in your class, when `Name`s stick around longer than they need to,
- The design remains testable with mocked objects, because you use interfaces.

Comment: You don't have memory leaks with a factory method either, if you `throw` when the identical name exists instead of returning an object, or if you return a `null` object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean the leaks that are not really leaks, but legitimate objects (the so-called "lingerers"). A simple static map would prevent its value objects from being released, while a map of weak references would hold them in memory only for as long as other live references are in existence.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  This might be one of the rare instances where a [`destructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) would be handy.

Comment: Too complex. It can be done like @weston answer, override equals and have the factory keep a collection of names.

Comment: @user1598390 One should make thing as simple as possible, but no simpler. weston's "solution" does not solve the OP's problem (there is no map), and a collection of names creates a lingerer memory leak (yes, there are memory leaks in Java).

Answer (score 1):

you should make the constructors private and create methods like `getNameInstance(String)`, if a  object with the same name already exists (based on a static class' hastable for instance), you return that reference, else you create a new object using your private constructor and add it to the hashtable

Comment: You've repeated what I said in the 3rd paragraph of the question. I was after alternative ways.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we answered almost at the same time because I checked for the answers before post mine. Actually, I tried to answer it on StackOverflown and than it was migrated.

Answer (score 1):

Try following.
You have to keep track of each object you create. For this purpose I'm using List.
And made class constructor private, so that pre-check can be applied before creating an instance

```
class UniqueName
    {
        private string Name;
        public int ID;
        private static int Count=0;
        static List<UniqueName> lt=new List<UniqueName>();

        private UniqueName(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            ID = ++Count;
        }

        public static UniqueName GetUniqueueInstance(string Name)
        {
            foreach (UniqueName un in lt)
            {
                if ( string.Compare( un.Name,Name,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==0)
                    return un;
            }

            UniqueName temp=new UniqueName(Name);
            lt.Add(temp);
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not Java? Have you written a pseudo-code? Or, in any other language? Please specify that explicitly.

Comment: Looks like C#. Akshay, you should learn other collections other than `List`. This would be a good fit for `Dictionary<string,UniqueName>`.